# Creating a slider that slides items in an arc / upper cricle

Tags: css, reactjs, animation, carousel, react-spring

I'm attempting to create a carousel that rotates items in a upper circle / arc fashion.
This is how it's supposed to roll: https://thumbs.gfycat.com/HastyTemptingBarnswallow-mobile.mp4

My initial thought is to have 1 element in the middle then one previous and next which are slightly rotated. Upon dragging it should move all items along the x-axis and slightly rotate. This is my attempt:

https://codesandbox.io/s/muddy-cdn-rbs34?from-embed

Problem is I can't seem to make the dragging animation very smooth. I might also just be overthinking this and go in the wrong direction. Any advice?

Comment: The easiest is probably to to put all elements on a "real" wheel and adjust the size of it that you only see a small part of the wheel. Then rotate the whole wheel. Add an remove elements in the not visible area depents on the rotate direction.

Comment: Yeah I think you have a good point, I'll try think about a real wheel in my next attempt. Thank you

Comment: Maybe [react-reveal](https://www.react-reveal.com/examples/common/Rotate/) would help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used the following link to create an effect like the one you want

https://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/08/09/building-a-circular-navigation-with-css-transforms/

You will have to adjust the CSS according to your UI.

```js
$('.opened-nav li').click(function(event) {
  var index = $(".opened-nav li").index(this);
  console.log(index)
  if (index >= 7) {
    return;
  }

  let startDeg = 80;
  $('#cn-wrapper').css({
    '-webkit-transform': 'scale(2) rotate(' + (startDeg - (index) * 40) + 'deg)',
    '-moz-transform': 'scale(2) rotate(' + (startDeg - (index) * 40) + 'deg)',
    '-ms-transform': 'scale(2) rotate(' + (startDeg - (index) * 40) + 'deg)',
    '-o-transform': 'scale(2) rotate(' + (startDeg - (index) * 40) + 'deg)',
    'transform': 'scale(2) rotate(' + (startDeg - (index) * 40) + 'deg)'
  });
  /* console.log(event) */
})
```

```css
@import url(http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/2.0/css/font-awesome.css);
* {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #f06060;
  color: #fff;
}

.csstransforms .cn-wrapper {
  font-size: 1em;
  width: 26em;
  height: 26em;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  bottom: -20em;
  left: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: -13em;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.1) rotate(40deg);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.1) rotate(40deg);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.1) rotate(40deg);
  transform: scale(0.1) rotate(40deg);
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

.csstransforms .opened-nav {
  border-radius: 50%;
  pointer-events: auto;
  -webkit-transform: scale(2) rotate(-40deg);
  -moz-transform: scale(2) rotate(-40deg);
  -ms-transform: scale(2) rotate(-40deg);
  transform: scale(2) rotate(-40deg);
}

.cn-overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  z-index: 2;
}

.cn-overlay.on-overlay {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.cn-button {
  border: none;
  background: none;
  color: #f06060;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  height: 3.5em;
  width: 3.5em;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -1.75em;
  bottom: -1.75em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 11;
}

.cn-button:hover,
.cn-button:active,
.cn-button:focus {
  color: #aa1010;
}

.csstransforms .cn-wrapper li {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -1.3em;
  margin-left: -10em;
  -webkit-transition: border .3s ease;
  -moz-transition: border .3s ease;
  transition: border .3s ease;
}

.csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.18em;
  height: 14.5em;
  width: 14.5em;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -7.25em;
  right: -7.25em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 1.8em;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-50deg) rotate(-70deg) scale(1);
  -ms-transform: skew(-50deg) rotate(-70deg) scale(1);
  -moz-transform: skew(-50deg) rotate(-70deg) scale(1);
  transform: skew(-50deg) rotate(-70deg) scale(1);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s, color 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s, color 0.3s;
  transition: opacity 0.3s, color 0.3s;
}

.csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a span {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  opacity: 0.7;
}


/* for a central angle x, the list items must be skewed by 90-x degrees
in our case x=40deg so skew angle is 50deg
items should be rotated by x, minus (sum of angles - 180)2s (for this demo) */
.csstransforms .cn-wrapper li{
  -webkit-transform: rotate(calc(-10deg + var(--n) * 360deg / 9)) skew(50deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(calc(-10deg + var(--n) * 360deg / 9)) skew(50deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(calc(-10deg + var(--n) * 360deg / 9)) skew(50deg);
  transform: rotate(calc(-10deg + var(--n) * 360deg / 9)) skew(50deg);
}



/*.csstransforms .cn-wrapper li:nth-child(odd) a {
  background-color: #a11313;
  background-color: hsla(0, 88%, 63%, 1);
}

.csstransforms .cn-wrapper li:nth-child(even) a {
  background-color: #a61414;
  background-color: hsla(0, 88%, 65%, 1);
}

.csstransforms .cn-wrapper li:last-child a {
  background-color: #a61414;
  background-color: hsl(343, 82%, 50%);
}*/


/* active style */

.csstransforms .cn-wrapper li.active a {
  background-color: #b31515;
  background-color: hsla(0, 88%, 70%, 1);
}


/* hover style */

.csstransforms .cn-wrapper li:not(.active) a:hover,
.csstransforms .cn-wrapper li:not(.active) a:active,
.csstransforms .cn-wrapper li:not(.active) a:focus {
  background-color: #b31515;
  background-color: hsla(0, 88%, 70%, 1);
}

.csstransforms .cn-wrapper li:not(.active) a:focus {
  position: fixed;
}


/* fallback */

.no-csstransforms .cn-button {
  display: none;
}

.no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper li {
  position: static;
  float: left;
  font-size: 1em;
  height: 5em;
  width: 5em;
  background-color: #eee;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 5em;
}

.no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a:last-child {
  border: none;
}

.no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a:hover,
.no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a:active,
.no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper li a:focus {
  background-color: white;
}

.no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper li.active a {
  background-color: #6F325C;
  color: #fff;
}

.no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper {
  font-size: 1em;
  height: 5em;
  width: 25.15em;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-left: -12.5em;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  left: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

@media screen and (max-width:480px) {
  .csstransforms .cn-wrapper {
    font-size: .68em;
  }
  .cn-button {
    font-size: 1em;
  }
  .csstransforms .cn-wrapper li {
    font-size: 1.52em;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:320px) {
  .no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper {
    width: 15.15px;
    margin-left: -7.5em;
  }
  .no-csstransforms .cn-wrapper li {
    height: 3em;
    width: 3em;
  }
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.6.2/modernizr.js"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/2972279885.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="cn-wrapper opened-nav" id="cn-wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li style="--n: 0"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-film"></i></a></li>
    <li style="--n: 1"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-headphones"></i></a></li>
    <li style="--n: 2"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bookmark"></i></a></li>
    <li style="--n: 3"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i></a></li>
    <li style="--n: 4"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-flag"></i></a></li>
    <li style="--n: 5"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-calculator"></i></a></li>
    <li style="--n: 6"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-coffee"></i></a></li>
    <li style="--n: 7"></li>
    <li style="--n: 8"></li>

  </ul>
</div>
```